# how to hide skill div on close class click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to hide div on object of div click
I am adding jquery path than my html code is here as it is and than after I am apply script to delete label class="main" with span and div class close1

but it's not perform

```
    <label class="main ">
        <span class="tag-value">mysql </span>
        <div class="close1">X</div>
    </label>
    <label class="main ">
        <span class="tag-value">codeigniter </span>
        <div class="close1">X</div>
    </label>
    <label class="main ">
        <span class="tag-value">ajax </span>
        <div class="close1">X</div>
    </label>
    <label class="main ">
        <span class="tag-value">jquery </span>
        <div class="close1">X</div>
    </label>




        <script>
            $(function(){       
                $(".close1").click(function(){
                    $(this).parent(".main").hide();
                 });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery lib in your head? Any conflicts? This **should** work

Comment: This work http://jsfiddle.net/meTLq/

Comment: Don't abuse the semantic label-element!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that JQ lib. is in the head of you r document, also, you can probably just use .parent()

http://jsfiddle.net/Yx4EU/

```
           <script>
                $(function(){       
                    $(".close1").click(function(){
                        $(this).parent().hide();
                     });
                });
            </script>
```

If this does not work, I suggest adding a fiddle for someone to look at.

Comment: Not sure why someone gave you a downvote... code and fiddle work perfectly.

Comment: @JRulle Probably because if this code work, the OP code should work aswell... http://jsfiddle.net/Yx4EU/1/. Did not downvote though

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, i give Mark credit for putting together the working JSFiddle to help the OP see how it works and spot his/her own issue since it isn't very clearly communicated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/8436y/1/
In this fiddle you will notice I haven't defined the parent, since it is not necessary (in this case).

http://jsfiddle.net/8436y/5/
here I have used the `.closest()` to define the closest `class="main"` , which also works ;)